# How do I build a tower up into empty space?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

How do I build a tower in Dwarf Fortress? My first instinct was to build an up|up/down stairway, but you can only do that down into empty space, not up.

Comment: lol @ the edition comment

Comment: @Juan I have no idea what you're talking about.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### <kbd>b</kbd> → <kbd>C</kbd> → <kbd>x</kbd>

not <kbd>d</kbd> → <kbd>i</kbd>

Comment: Why the downvote? This is exactly what I was missing.

Comment: It might be because of the lack of explanation in the answer. The DF menu hotkeys are correct, but to someone unfamiliar with DF they won't understand that his answer means "Use Build/Construction/Up-down stairs" and not "Designate/Up-down stairs". The difference, of course, is that the first allows building up-down stairs in open spaces, where the second carves them out of un-mined stone/earth.

Answer (score 0):

Use walls, floors, and ramps. When  you are a level higher, build one staircase down and one staircase up. I think that should work.

Comment: Or you could just build a tower of up/down staircases like anthony suggested 3 years ago.